# Recycler View Not Reading Big Volley data with params in android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using volley to receive the data from a data source, the problem is with the recycler view if I do something on a query like adding parameters it does not work. It there is any problem with the Volley?

```
public void getting locations() {
    String url = "URL REMOVED";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this); // this = context
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONObject status = null;
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                        JSONArray jr = jObj.getJSONArray("products");
                        for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jb1 = jr.getJSONObject(i);
                            String title = jb1.getString("title");
                            Log.d("Title",""+title);
                            String img = jb1.getString("featured_src");
                            JSONArray a = jb1.getJSONArray("categories");
                            String category = "";

                            lstBook.add(new Book(title,"rAJA","Description book",img));

                        }




                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d("EROOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOR", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");

        return headers;
    }

};
jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
queue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

}

The problem is if the URL is products it will show the data otherwise it will not.

Comment: I am able to get the data when I tried adding the params as you mentioned. What is the error message or which data is missing for you? I am not able to access your logcat.

Comment: stack is the password for logcat . when ever i try to add params like ?page=2 or ?filter in volley url it just donst load things up . and the reason why it do that is becasue volley is unable to read the full json data .

Comment: https://ibb.co/inCmho screenshot image

Comment: The logcat is not printing the whole content. This does not mean that it is not loading the data. Try to print the title alone inside the for loop and verify.

Comment: I can verify that it is actually printing all the data, can you guide me some more little i am placing this data in an recyclerview so when i make simple request it shows but when i add parms it doesnot

Comment: https://ibb.co/fGnaa8 this is the result I get if I don't add any parameters, but when i add params it just gets vanished.

Comment: Can you please share the recyclerview implementation?

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/JzQdLnEl is the code MAinactivity

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/30ZD3Dyq and here is the recycler view adapter

Comment: Share you model class Book as well

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/ODMXJ9b8

Comment: does that help ? did you find anything @somia

Comment: yes.. I will post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare myAdapter as a private variable and change the code as mentioned below.

Add the line `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after                             `lstBook.add(new Book(title,"rAJA","Description book",img));` and `myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);`

```
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
 {
    JSONObject jb1 = jr.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = jb1.getString("title");
    String img = jb1.getString("featured_src");
    JSONArray a = jb1.getJSONArray("categories");
    String category = "";
    lstBook.add(new Book(title,"rAJA","Description book",img));
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and

```
myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,lstBook);
myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```